# Linear Interpolation of video frames in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, interpolation, blending

I was trying to achieve the so called  'ghosting effect' from the LFI method for inserting frames in OpenCV, Python.

However, the output does not seem to produce the results. I used blending function of OpenCV to calculate the frames in between.

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test_vid.avi')

starting = True
prev_frame = np.uint8([250])

while(True):

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if starting==True:
        prev_frame = frame
        starting = False
    else:
        for i in range(1,10):
            weight = i/10
            #get the blended frames in between
            mid_frame = cv2.addWeighted(prev_frame,weight,frame,1-weight,0)     
            cv2.imshow('frame2',mid_frame)

        #cv2.imshow('frame',frame)     
        prev_frame = frame

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result seems to be as if its the same frame as the current frame (no sign of any actual blending taking place)

Comment: You don't have any `waitKey` calls between the 9 consecutive calls to `cv2.imshow('frame2',mid_frame)` in the inner loop. That means only the last `mid_frame` will be shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it.